# Invalid Certificate

Tags: php, web, certificate, hosting, ssl-certificate

I am trying to solve a problem on my site. Some pages are displayed without any problem by Firefox but other browsers like Chrome, Safari or IE display an Invalid Certificate/Website not trusted error message.

After some research on Google, I see that the solutions given are usually on the client side. I'm looking for a server-side solution (in PHP). Firstly I would like to know more about this error.

Here's the error message displayed by Chrome : "You tried to access the domain xxxxxxxxx.com, but the server presented a certificate issued by an entity not approved by the operating system of your computer. This may mean that the server has generated its own security certificate, in which case Chromium can not be relied upon to validate credentials. It is also possible that a hacker has intercepted communications.
Do not continue with this operation, especially if you have never seen this warning before for this site."

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you provide the details of the error, not just the error title.

Comment: Are you using curl in script? This can affected an errors?

Comment: Make sure you have installed the full certificate chain on the server.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/325120/curl-ssl-issue-with-rapidssl-certificates

Comment: @PeeHaa Can you give me more details please?

Comment: Can you output your hosts file? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29 What's Os are you using?

Comment: If you have bought your certificate through an intermediate supplier you would have to install the complete chain. Also you may want to test what actually is going on: http://www.digicert.com/help/

Answer (score 0):

Are you properly set a virtualhosts?

```
Listen 443

NameVirtualHost *:443
SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off

<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /www/example1
  ServerName www.example.com

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
  DocumentRoot /www/example2
  ServerName www.example2.org

</VirtualHost>
```

Anyway, make sure that is properly set up cert on vhosts such as example:

```
SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile /path/to/your_domain_name.crt
 SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/to/your_private.key
 SSLCertificateChainFile /path/to/DigiCertCA.crt
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you need to install your server's signing certificate (or server certificate if self-signed) as part of your PC's trusted certificates.
What the complaint is about, is that your custom certificate has not been issued by a recognizes CA